# Python 3.7.6 PIP 18.1 Not seeing Setuptools durring pyinstaller upgrade

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.7

Was using Python 3.6 and pyinstaller 3.3.1 -no issues
Upgraded to Python 3.7.6
pip list of installed packages:
altgraph    0.17
et-xmlfile  1.0.1
future      0.18.2
jdcal       1.4.1
macholib    1.14
openpyxl    3.0.3
pefile      2019.4.18
pip         18.1
PyInstaller 3.3.1
pypiwin32   223
pywin32     227
setuptools  45.2.0

I have used the pip command (in the same format as bellow) to install other packages with no issues

Using command: 
pip install --proxy http://user:password@my.company.proxy.com:8080 --upgrade pyinstaller

I get the following error:

> Collecting pyinstaller
>
> Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/c9/c3f9bc64eb11eee6a824686deba6129884c8cbdf70e750661773b9865ee0/PyInstaller-3.6.tar.gz
>
> Installing build dependencies ... error    Complete output from
>   command "c:\program files\python37\python.exe" -m pip install
>   --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\mipXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6eabc0h2
>   --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools>=38.2.5 wheel:    Collecting
>   setuptools>=38.2.5
>
> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
>
> Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
>
> Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
>
> Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
>
> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   setuptools>=38.2.5 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
>   for setuptools>=38.2.5 You are using pip version 18.1, however version
>   20.0.2 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I have upgraded pip and then downgraded it.

I uninstalled Python 3.6 re-installed 3.7.6.

I tried powershell to  set HTTP_PROXY=my.company.proxy.com and set HTTPS_Proxy=my.company.proxy.com

I tried powershell to netsh winhttp set proxy "my.company.proxy.com"

All this being said, it looks like pip is not seeing that setuptools is already at 45.2.0. This is based on this line in the error text => Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=38.2.5 (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for setuptools>=38.2.5

Comment: The problem is not related to Python, `pip` or `setuptools`. `getaddrinfo failed` — you have a network problem. Perhaps you're behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes I am behind a Proxy. However, I had no issues intalling openpyxl, pylint, kivy, kivy_examples, pandas, pyinstaller version 3.3.1,  and pymsql.  Also, according to pip list setuptools is already above the 38.2.5 minimum required.  So why is it trying to upgrade setuptools?